# Centos server provides javascript for localhost but not local lan

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, asterisk, javascript

I have a centos 6 server running an asterisk, freepbx, and apache 2.2.25. On this server, the apache server serves up a webpage called fop2. I've talked to the developer, and he says the files are all in line, and that the apache server isn't having any issues, but that it's a networking issue of some sort.

Webpage displays:

> We're building the buildings as fast as we can`

chrome Java console states that it is unable to serve files:

```
Failed to load resource
x.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
x.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
x.each.x.(anonymous function) @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
x.extend.getScript @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
(anonymous function) @ boot.js:7
```

However, tunneling into the sever with putty/ssh, I can get to the webpage just fine.

Outside of iptables, I cannot think of any issue at all.

I'm at a complete loss, could really use some help :)

EDIT: RDP'd into server yesterday, I had the same error. Only change I've made was running the bash autoconfig-buttons-freepbx.sh and changing the way I rdp into the server.
Now when I navigate to https://192.168.0.254/fop2/ I get a new error "Flash Player Version 9 or newer required One moment please". 
Here is the odd part...
http://192.168.0.254/fop2/ works. http connection was tried yesterday rdp'd into the server over vpn (now it's a forwarded rdp with acls). 
Not sure if there are flash updates going through that changes the ssl security requirements, not sure. I've had issues recently with software and self signed ssl certificates. Very much at a loss right now. Thank you so much guys for your help. I don't actually know what the resolution is, I'd guess the buttons.sh, but I've no idea :\

Comment: It would help if you included the relevant apache configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my steps from my last setup of FOP2, I suspect step 8 was borked if you don't have /usr/local/fop2/buttons_custom.cfg (not .cnf sorry) or fop2 db and tables setup:

1. cd /usr/src
2. wget http://www.fop2.com/download/centos64 -O fop2.tgz
3. tar zxvf fop2.tgz
4. cd fop2
5. make install
6. /usr/local/fop2/generate_override_contexts.pl -write
7. /usr/local/fop2/fop2_server --test
8. **HERE IS WHERE YOU MUST LOGIN WITH A WEB BROWSER FIRST** http://domain/fop2/admin (this creates all the buttons, db tables, etc)
9. service fop2 start (back to CLI)

At this point it seems like you do have a few buttons showing BECAUSE you manually invoked /usr/local/fop2/autoconfig-buttons-freepbx.sh, but that is not the only script that runs on initial login to the manager gui.

Your asterisk db should contain these fop tables:

fop2ButtonContext, fop2buttons, fop2contexts, fop2GroupButton, fop2groups, fop2PermGroup, fop2permissions, fop2plugins, fop2recordings, fop2settings, fop2templates, fop2UserContext, fop2UserGroup, fop2UserPlugin, fop2users, fop2UserTemplate

Login into the management console, make some users, test all functionality. Use updated flash and an updated broswer. Get FOP2 fully functional first before tackling the SSL issue (although I've never had any special config for 80 vs 443, both just work).

Again /usr/local/fop2/fop2_server -X 511 will give you valuable debug information to help chase issues

You may well have a separate SSL issue, but this all seems to be FOP2 acting up from what you've said so far and it seems like you've made a step in the right direction.

Sorry for the disjointed answer yesterday, was on mobile, and also my first time posting, so can't comment as I don't have 50 rep.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! After creating a new extension in freepbx, the new extension and the 3 other new extensions that hadn't shown up all appeared as buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup on three servers and MAY be able to help.
Is this an initial install? I seem to remember a step about getting into `fopmanager` before ever accessing fop to create the buttons. You could check `/usr/local/fop2/buttons_custom.cnf` for output to see if the `autoconfig-buttons-freepbx.sh` has run. Or also check `phpmyadmin` for `fop2` tables and data.

You can also invoke `fop2server` with a debug option I think it's `-X 511` to get more detailed info. I can log in when I get home and confirm or help you compare files, but mine's a lil customized. The developer is pretty good about troubleshooting info, he's helped me out several times already and has even fixed a few bugs we found, I'm surprised he couldn't point you in the right direction.

Comment: This seems to be a partial answer.  Your questions should be made as comments on the inital post, anything concrete you have for the OP to try can be in the answer section.

Comment: Did not see
ran bash autoconfig-buttons-freepbx.sh
Actually, still do not see usr/local/fop2/buttons_custom.cnf :\
Oddly enough, the fop2/ page is now just spinning "externally", via tunnel/localhost I can still get into fop2 without issues. Checking phpmyadmin...

Comment: Alright, looks like there's a bigger issue here, I have one server on which fop2 is working. I checked the databases, my working server has a separate fop2 db outside of the asterisk database that the others do not have, however the separate fop2 database only contains the following tables: fop2recordings and visual_phonebook, so that's not it.
otherwise, in the asterisk database, the tables are all over the place. I cannot find a single instance in which all of the tables are *exactly* the same. The tables that exist in the one working instance do in fact exist in the broken servers

Answer (score 0):

The default apache configuration restricts access to most locations to secure your system.  Certain standard locations have less restrictive access.  Review you configuration for lines containing `Require`, `Allow` or `Deny`.  These will be inside a specification indicating what they apply to.

Check the directory tree containing the resources you can't reach for a `.htaccess` files as these could contain additional restrictions.

Try using a tool which allows you to see the headers of the failing requests.  The first line should include an status code and a short explanation of the status code.

Check your apache errorlog which should log any failures based on security restrictions.

Comment: vi /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: vi /var/log/httpd/error_log
Not seeing anything  there regarding fop2.
 vi /var/log/httpd/access_log
Mostly:
50.255.119.13 - - [01/Sep/2015:16:45:22 -0500] "GET /fop2/audio/DTMF_9.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 360 "http://192.168.30.254/fop2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

Comment: htaccess is enabled for var/www/html/admin and maint/, but I don't see anything for /var/www/fop2 or /var/www/fop2/admin/ (which I can gain access to).